# Make a responsive navigation bar with a search box

Tags: html, css, search, navbar

I have a navigation bar, an example of which is available here:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/4uq6y5fa.

This displays as expected when all the elements fit on the screen, but if I resize the window, bits of the menu start disappearing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS media queries:

```
@media only screen (//defined for particular width)
{
//code of nav bar and search box
}
```

e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
         background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define widths and heights in percentages(relatively), using em instead of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what your point is, do you want to make the menu responsive or do you want to know what the problem is?

As for making it responsive, use media queries.

> **W3schools**, The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

So for example you make your width 100% for the screen size of 1920x1080 and 50% for the size of 1024x720. So your nav will "jump" to the 50% when someone resizes the website.

Comment: This is on the borderline between a comment and an answer. If you need clarification, you should ask for that first, then answer with the new information.

Comment: That is why I didn't comment, I didn't need a clarification. @BFDatabaseAdmin, Iam just pointing out that the OP is not clear enough with his/her post

Comment: I'd say if you ask a question in your answer, you're asking for clarification.